# How to catch errors in a sequential promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm building a synchronous series of Promises like so:

```
let order = [fn1, fn2, fn3];
let result = Promise.resolve();
order.reduce((chain, task) => {
    return chain.then(task);
}, result);
```

(via the 'Executing Promises in Series' section of [this article](http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/)). This runs everything in series like I'd expect, but having issues with catching errors/where to put the `catch` block.

Comment: Side note: promises are executed asynchronously even if resolved and chained like this.

Comment: A few thoughts: these aren't really synchronous, they're sequential (all promises are async, always... that sounds like pedantry, but if you were mutating state in the outside world, it would make a huge difference); if you wanted to independently handle error cases, based on converting a failure to a success for the next call in the sequence, then you need to change your data-format, or you need to accept that any one could fail, and allow the consumer to catch the error; lastly, if you don't save the promise that comes out the other side, you don't get to pass it around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put it at the end, where you'd normally continue with the chain as well:

```
[fn1, fn2, fn3].reduce((chain, task) => {
    return chain.then(task);
}, Promise.resolve()).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Remember that the `reduce` expands to

```
Promise.resolve().then(fn1).then(fn2).then(fn3).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: How can I catch errors for each Promise separately?

Comment: @RishabGupta Put the `.catch()` inside each of the functions if you want separate handlers. Or use `return chain.then(task).catch(handler)`, but notice that this means the execution continues with the next task after a failure (using the result of the `handler` as the argument).

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a catch block. The `reduce` will return the first rejected promise in the chain. To see this, write out what the `reduce` will actually produce:

```
const resolve = () => Promise.resolve(), reject = () => Promise.reject();
const promises = [resolve, reject, resolve];

const result = Promise.resolve()
   .then(resolve).then(reject).then(resolve);
```

The first `then` handler will be invoked, resulting in a fulfilled promise, so the next `then` handler will be invoked, this time resulting in a rejected promise, so the final `then` will not invoke its handler and will "pass through" the rejected promise, which will become the result of the entire expression, and which you can catch with

```
result.catch(() => alert("Hey Mom, one of the chained promises rejected"))
```